# Gollum Wiki - undefined method `new' for Redcarpet:Module

Tags: github, gollum-wiki

I'm trying to use [Gollumn Wiki](https://github.com/github/gollum), so I could edit my GitHub Wiki but I can't seem to get it to work.

I'm on Ubuntu 11.10, 64Bit.

I've tried this as well with Ruby 1.9, also the same error.

I cloned my [GitHub Wiki git repository](https://github.com/markmandel/ColdDoc/wiki/_access) for my project, fired up Gollum, and this is the error I recieved:

NoMethodError at /
undefined method `new' for Redcarpet:Module

The full stack trace is:

```
:public is no longer used to avoid overloading Module#public, use :public_folder instead
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/gollum-1.3.1/bin/../lib/gollum/frontend/app.rb:17
[2011-12-06 15:20:15] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-12-06 15:20:15] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30) [x86_64-linux]
== Sinatra/1.3.1 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2011-12-06 15:20:20] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=22017 port=4567 
NoMethodError - undefined method `new' for Redcarpet:Module:
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/gollum-1.3.1/lib/gollum/markup.rb:463:in `render'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/gollum-1.3.1/lib/gollum/page.rb:171:in `formatted_data'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/gollum-1.3.1/bin/../lib/gollum/frontend/app.rb:190:in `show_page_or_file'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/gollum-1.3.1/bin/../lib/gollum/frontend/app.rb:42:in `GET /'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1211:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1211:in `compile!'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:772:in `[]'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:772:in `route!'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:788:in `route_eval'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:772:in `route!'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:821:in `process_route'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:819:in `catch'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:819:in `process_route'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:771:in `route!'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:770:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:770:in `route!'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:886:in `dispatch!'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:706:in `call!'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:871:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:871:in `catch'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:871:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:706:in `call!'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:692:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-protection-1.1.4/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:22:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-protection-1.1.4/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb:16:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-protection-1.1.4/lib/rack/protection/json_csrf.rb:17:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-protection-1.1.4/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:47:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-protection-1.1.4/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:22:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/nulllogger.rb:9:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/showexceptions.rb:21:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1334:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1403:in `synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1334:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1295:in `run!'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/gollum-1.3.1/bin/gollum:125
/usr/local/bin/gollum:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/gollum:19
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since this seems like something that needs to be fixed in `gollum` itself, I made a [pull request to fix this problem](https://github.com/github/gollum/pull/271).

Comment: [Related pull request](https://github.com/github/gollum/pull/242)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try reinstalling redcarpet like this:

```
gem uninstall redcarpet
gem install redcarpet --version=1.17.2
```

If using bundler, put in your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'redcarpet', '1.17.2'
gem 'gollum'
```

Comment: According to http://github.com/tanoku/redcarpet/blob/master/README.markdown
> Redcarpet version 2 is not backwards-compatible with the 1.X versions. 
Lame! This update broke the site generator I use, Jekyll. Amusingly, Redcarpet and Jekyll are both made by GitHub. It's discourteous that they broke other folk's software, embarassing that they broke their own!

Answer (score 8):

I am trying to use Gollum as my documentation for new projects and this problem hit me recently also.  To solve this I isolated the changes using Bundler.  In my cloned Gollum directory on my local machine I did the following:

```
# Create a Gemfile with the following:
source "http://rubygems.org"
gem 'redcarpet', '1.17.2'
gem 'gollum'
```

Next just run `bundle install` to set everything up.  When you are ready to start the gollum server run `bundle exec gollum` from the command line.

This will give you a nice isolated gollum server using the gems you specifically bundled and will solve this problem discussed in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same "undefined method 'new' for Redcarpet:Module" error after running a `bundle update.`

Similar to above, this installed version 2 of the gem along side version 1.  I could have gone back to v1 as described above, but since I"m not actually using a system that required the first gen of the gem, I removed version 1 and went with v2.  Easy.